# Pycharm display an error in the terminal when I run python3 manage.py runserver

Tags: server, pycharm

I am facing errors while trying to follow Django tutorial. I reach to the point to add and load an HTML template.

I deleted main.py python file but when I run my code I still find this error:

```
/home/timgrand/PycharmProjects/Pyshop/venv/bin/python: can't open file
'/home/timgrand/PycharmProjects/Pyshop/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Another error on server page.

[image]

Output of `tree -I venv /home/timgrand/PycharmProjects/Pyshop/`

[image]

Comment: when creating a new project it was there by default but I deleted it even before including django

Comment: should I write the `tree -I venv /home/timgrand/PycharmProjects/Pyshop/`code on my pycharm terminal?

Comment: Am following two tutorials for Django and I created one template for reading html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint to check

- Check folder & files permissions

  ```
  ls -lR -I venv  /home/timgrand/PycharmProjects/Pyshop
  ```
- Check app templates setup

  ```
  TEMPLATES = [
          ...
          'APP_DIRS': True,
  ```

  If app is active

  ```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
      ...
      'products.apps.ProductsConfig',
      'products', #this format still works too
      ...
  ```
- Or move `templates` from products app to parent project director `Pyshop`

  ```
  mv /home/timgrand/PycharmProjects/Pyshop/products/templates /home/timgrand/PycharmProjects/Pyshop/
  ```

For the other error about `main.py`, you need to create an empty project when using PyCharm CE edition and then add Django existing project to it.

By unchecking the `main.py` box in Project creation wizard. See the screenshot.

[image: main.py option box in the wizard of new project of PyCharm CE]

Comment: I already have the templates directory in Pyshop with index.html inside

Comment: I also tried to add 'templates' in my 'settings.py' in the DIR section ie.

Comment: I've tried the code for moving templates but I still get an error

Comment: `mv: cannot stat '/home/timgrand/PycharmProjects/Pyshop/products/templates': No such file or directory`  my APP_DIRS is already set to true. I even tried to begin another new file , everything works well until I introduce templates then it stops working

Comment: I've done that. Will you be able to see it?

Comment: `https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CYfV2ngPw8/` thats the link to the pastebin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115568/discussion-between-grand-and-user-dz).